# can't run .sh or .py file directly from bashoperater

Tags: bash, airflow

I am trying to run python script from bash command in airflow, I even tried running the .sh file from the bash command which may trigger the python file. But it keeps giving me error "No such file or directory". I just can't figure out the path to be given to the file.

I have tried specifying different paths to reach the directory also changed permissions of the files to 777 but still no change

```
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='requestpage',
    bash_command="/home/username/runfile.sh ",
    dag=dag,
)
```

above is the defined task but it never executes.

Comment: how about you start with trying to **infer the current-working-directory** for the process in which your `BashOperator`'s task is spawned? giving `bash_command="pwd"` or `bash_command="tree"` should help

Comment: i did i printed the pwd command also tried ls command ls , ls ../, ls ../../ at the third ls command i got root directory listed. So i tried making my path to ../../home/something.... but it did not work.

Comment: I am stuck at it since last many hours. I have tried so many things. The BashOperator seems to be creating a temporary directory for itself. But how to excute the bash file then.

Comment: Could you post the full error? Is the file not found for the .sh file you're triggering or the .py file?

Comment: it is for the .sh file.